# Codeigniter Multidimensional Array to Database

Tags: php, arrays, database, codeigniter

I'm trying to insert an array into a database table as separate rows. The array is generated from a table where the user can add additional rows. Can't get my head around what is going wrong!

Here is the view

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="parts">
  <thead class="table-success">
    <tr>
      <th class="table-success">Quantity</th>
      <th class="table-success">Parts</th>
      <th class="table-success">Fitted</th>
      <th class="table-success">Required</th>
      <th class="table-success">Cost</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <input type="hidden" name="job_no[]" value="<?php echo $job_number; ?>" />
      <td><input type="number" name="parts_qty[]" class="form-control" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="parts_description[]" class="form-control" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="parts_fitted[]" class="form-control" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="parts_required[]" class="form-control" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="parts_cost[]" class="form-control" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" id="addRow"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true"> </span> Add Row </button>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addRow").click(function(){
            $("#parts").append("<tr><input type='hidden' name='job_no[]' value='<?php echo $job_number; ?>' /><td><input type='number' name='parts_qty[]' class='form-control' /></td><td><input type='text' name='parts_description[]' class='form-control' /></td><td><input type='text' name='parts_fitted[]' class='form-control' /></td><td><input type='text' name='parts_required[]' class='form-control' /></td><td><input type='text' name='parts_cost[]' class='form-control' /></td></tr>");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Please note this is part of a larger form so not showing the submit buttons e.t.c

My Controller function looks like this

```
function add_parts_db()
    {
        $parts = array (
                    'job_number'    => $this->input->post('job_no'),
                    'quantity'      => $this->input->post('parts_qty'),
                    'parts'         => $this->input->post('parts_description'),
                    'fitted'        => $this->input->post('parts_fitted'),
                    'required'      => $this->input->post('parts_required'),
                    'cost'          => $this->input->post('parts_cost')
                );

                $this->service_model->add_parts_db($parts);
                redirect('service', 'refresh');
    }
```

Here is the array being generated with some sample input in the table

```
Array
(
    [job_number] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2008
            [1] => 2008
            [2] => 2008
        )

    [quantity] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [parts] => Array
        (
            [0] => Part 1
            [1] => Part 2
            [2] => Parts 3
        )

    [fitted] => Array
        (
            [0] => Fitted 1
            [1] => Fitted 1
            [2] => Fitted 3
        )

    [required] => Array
        (
            [0] => Required 1
            [1] => Required 2
            [2] => Required 3
        )

    [cost] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1.00
            [1] => 2.00
            [2] => 3.00
        )

)
```

Finally my model which I want to insert each item of the array into the database table as a separate row.

```
function add_parts_db($parts)
{
    $this->db->insert_batch('parts', $parts);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

I would like the above array to be inserted into the database as separate rows so should look something like this

[image]

I'm getting the following error when submitting the form

```
    Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0, 1, 2) VALUES ('2008','2008','2008'), ('1','2','3'), ('Part 1','Part 2','Parts' at line 1

INSERT INTO `parts` (0, 1, 2) VALUES ('2008','2008','2008'), ('1','2','3'), ('Part 1','Part 2','Parts 3'), ('Fitted 1','Fitted 1','Fitted 3'), ('Required 1','Required 2','Required 3'), ('1.00','2.00','3.00')

Filename: models/Service_model.php

Line Number: 33
```

I think the problem might be in my jQuery/Javascript which I'm not quite understanding. I can set the initial key to 0 using name="parts[0][jobnumber]" but then in my jQuery I don't think it's recognising the variable properly

```
var $i = 1;
        $("#addRow").click(function(){
                $("#parts").append("<tr><input type='hidden' name='parts[$i][jobnumber]' value='<?php echo $job_number; ?>' /><td><input type='number' name='parts[$i][qty]' class='form-control' /></td><td><input type='text' name='parts[$i][description]' class='form-control' /></td><td><input type='text' name='parts[i][fitted]' class='form-control' /></td><td><input type='text' name='parts[$i][required]' class='form-control' /></td><td><input type='text' name='parts[$i][cost]' class='form-control' /></td></tr>");
                i++;
        });
```

I think dumping the array looks like it's going to pull the correct array format through but it's not getting it because of my inept jQuery.

```
 ["parts"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(5) {
      ["jobnumber"]=>
      string(4) "2002"
      ["qty"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["description"]=>
      string(7) "parts 3"
      ["required"]=>
      string(10) "required 3"
      ["cost"]=>
      string(4) "3.00"
    }
    ["i"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["fitted"]=>
      string(8) "fitted 3"
    }
  }
```

This is showing a syntax error if I go with the second reply
[image: Code Error]

@Bhaumik Mehta

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [job_number] => 2002
                [quantity] => 1
                [parts] => parts 1
                [fitted] => Fitted 1
                [required] => Required 1
                [cost] => 1.00
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [job_number] => 2002
                [quantity] => 2
                [parts] => Part 2
                [fitted] => Fitted 2
                [required] => Required 2
                [cost] => 2.00
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [job_number] => 2002
                [quantity] => 3
                [parts] => Parts 3
                [fitted] => Fitted 3
                [required] => Required 3
                [cost] => 3.00
            )

    )
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are structuring your array is wrong for what you are trying to do, as you are ending up with an array for each database column, and what you want is an array for each database row.

Instead of this, where you add the parts description to an array

```
<td><input type="text" name="parts_description[]" class="form-control" /></td>
```

You need something like this:

```
<td><input type="text" name="job[$i][parts_description]" class="form-control" /></td>
```

Where `$i=0` for the first row, and then you increment it by 1 with each new row added by your jQuery function.

This way you will end up with the `$_POST['job']` variable containing multiple arrays with each one corresponding to a single row on your table, which you can then loop over to insert into the database

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I'm still struggling with it. I tried using the method above but I can't get the array into a format to add to the database.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST);` return if you submit the form? Do you understand what is wrong with this statement in your question or would it help if I explained? `INSERT INTO parts (0, 1, 2) VALUES ('2008','2008','2008'), ('1','2','3'), (Part 1,'Part 2','Parts 3'), ('Fitted 1','Fitted 1','Fitted 3'), ('Required 1','Required 2','Required 3'), ('1.00','2.00','3.00')`

Comment: I think the problem might be in my jQuery/Javascript which I'm not quite understanding. I can set the initial key to 0 using name="parts[0][jobnumber]"

Comment: I have appended the jQuery and dumped array to original post

Comment: You have a tiny error in your jQuery. You have defined you variable as `$i` but on this line you have just used `i++` without the `$`

Answer (score 0):

While this solution might come handy. It's not the ideal solution.

```
function add_parts_db()
    {
        $parts = array (
                    'job_number'    => $this->input->post('job_no'),
                    'quantity'      => $this->input->post('parts_qty'),
                    'parts'         => $this->input->post('parts_description'),
                    'fitted'        => $this->input->post('parts_fitted'),
                    'required'      => $this->input->post('parts_required'),
                    'cost'          => $this->input->post('parts_cost')
                );

           $partsArr = [];
           $totalCnt = count($parts['job_number']);
          for($key=0; $key < $totalCnt ;$key++)
          {
           $partsArr[] = [
              'job_number' => $parts['job_number'][$key] , 
              'quantity'   => $parts['quantity'][$key] , 
              'parts'      => $parts['parts'][$key] , 
              'fitted'     => $parts['fitted'][$key] , 
              'required'   => $parts['required'][$key] , 
              'cost'       => $parts['cost'][$key]]; 

           }
            //just make sure that your service_model uses `insert_batch` method to  insert data
            $this->service_model->add_parts_db($partsArr);
            redirect('service', 'refresh');
     }
```

For more information read [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::insert_batch)

Comment: Thanks. I tried using the code but I get syntax errors at $partsArr = []; and also in the loop.

Comment: can you share screenshot of what error are you getting ??

Comment: Please do a `print_r` of `$partsArr` array and share that screenshot.